# Is it possilbe to use an OpenPGP private key to sign a file via OpenSSL?

Tags: openssl, digital-signature, pgp, gnupg, openpgp

Is it possible to use an exported OpenPGP private key to sign a file via OpenSSL?

I've tried this:

```
$ gpg2 --export-secret-keys --no-armor 84E2C2E5 > secret.key
$ openssl rsautl -sign -in testfile -inkey secret.key -out test.sign
```

But that gives me this error:

> unable to load Private Key 140543167485592:error:0906D06C:PEM
>   routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:701:Expecting: ANY
>   PRIVATE KEY

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While OpenPGP and X.509 mostly share the same cryptographic algorithms, they have completely different representations of the key material. GnuPG (or to be more specific, `gpg`; `gpgsm` implements S/MIME and X.509 but not OpenPGP and is also part of GnuPG) does not "speak" X.509, OpenSSL does not support OpenPGP.

While you could well extract the numbers forming the keys and then construct a new key of the other format, these would still seem like different keys: due to the different protocols you cannot read messages encrypted in the other system, you cannot verify signatures issued by this. Even the keys are not obviously comparable, key identifiers are constructed differently, and finally the two systems share different trust systems.

To wrap up: theoretically you could construct a new key (not really convert it, as meta information is lost and other information is missing). There is no actual use in doing so, thus nobody cared about writing proper tooling for the process.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the key to the correct format -

```
gpg2 --export-secret-keys
     --export-options export-reset-subkey-passwd,export-minimal,no-export-attributes 
     --no-armor 84E2C2E5 | openpgp2ssh 84E2C2E5 > id_rsa
```

Why are you trying to do this? Why not just sign the document with gpg?

```
gpg2 --sign document.doc
```

Comment: I'm trying to examine if a "gpg-signature" differs from an "openssl-signature". Your first line does not work for me. Although the id_rsa-file is generated, openpgp2ssh says: "We cannot handle encrypted secret keys.  Skipping!" And `openssl rsautl -sign -in test2 -inkey id_rsa -out test.sign` does not work either.

Comment: @user1511417 see update to arguments to export encrypted.

Comment: It's still not working: gpg2 does not know the export option 'export-reset-subkey-passwd'

Comment: I've version gpg (GnuPG) 2.1.11 installed here.

Comment: You can easily determine how _RSA_ signatures compare in GPG and OpenSSL by reading the docs; also note both programs can do other signatures besides RSA. OpenSSL does several different kinds of RSA signature, and `rsautl -sign` with default `-pkcs` is actually not standard PKCS1v1.5, for that you need `pkeyutl -sign` with an RSA key and `-pkeyopt digest:$md` or usually better `[dgst -]$md -sign` with RSA as explained in about a dozen Qs already; start with my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767660/multiple-openssl-rsa-signing-methods-produce-different-results

Comment: Also look at OpenSSL's CMS and S/MIME signatures, both detached/clear and embedded, which are a much closer analog to GPG/PGP.

Comment: SSH is using another key format than OpenSSL is doing, this is not answering the question after all.

Comment: @JensErat - OpenSSH private keys are usually stored in .pem format - which is what OpenSSL uses. OP specifically asked about private keys. If you want to get an OpenSSL public key you can then do ssh-keygen -f private.pem -y > public.pub